# NSNotification will not dismiss modal view

Tags: iphone, modalviewcontroller, nsnotifications, nsnotificationcenter

**Task:**
I have a navigation controller that pushes a modalview, called login.  This login view has a button that pushes another modalview, called signup. If a user signs up the the signup modal AND the login modal should dismiss.  I have created an nsnotification within the login view that waits for a post from the signup submission action.

**Problem** The login receives the notification, but does not dismiss the login view. I know that the method runs, because an NSLog fires.

Login viewDidLoad

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(dismiss) name@"SignedUp" object nil];
```

Login dismiss

```
NSLog(@"Dismiss"); // this fires
[self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated: YES];
```

Signup method (Child Controller)

```
[self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated: YES];
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"SignedUp" object:[self parentViewController]];
```

I have also tried this after calling dismiss in the signup method

```
[self.parentViewController dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```

**Edit** I'm not pushing these controllers. I am using `presentModalViewController`

Comment: have u got the solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why are you dismissing them one at a time, if you intend to dismiss the entire stack ? This might not be a problem with Notifications. You can just pop the entire stack using

```
[[[self parentViewController] parentViewController] dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```

And then if you wish to show it again, Just make it the `presentModalViewController` again.

I am sure you can get a lot of input through https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=Dismiss+multiple+modal+controllers

Comment: This is the basically the solution. I've had to moved the dismiss method to the root most view of the presented modals and added the code [self.navigationController dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];

Answer (score 0):

How do you present your modal view? The reason I ask is that you say 'navigation controller that pushes a modalview'.

If you're using `pushViewController:animated:` then it's not a modal view and you need to use `popViewControllerAnimated:` to make it go away again.

Comment: Oops. I'm using some confusing verbage.  I'm using presentModalViewController

Comment: In that case, ignore my answer completely! I can only assume that because you have nested modal view controllers it's getting confused but your code should work. I'll have a think . . .